# "ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'processor'" error when running "airflow standalone"

Tags: python, macos, airflow

I am new to airflow. I created a virtual environment and followed the steps in https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start.html. In the end I gave "airflow standalone" and got "ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'processor'"

```
(venv) hgovea155@INSML-CPXX7WW AFDocProj % airflow standalone
Unable to load the config, contains a configuration error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/config.py", line 563, in configure
    handler = self.configure_handler(handlers[name])
  File "/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/config.py", line 736, in configure_handler
    result = factory(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/log/file_processor_handler.py", line 49, in __init__
    Path(self._get_log_directory()).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
  File "/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/pathlib.py", line 1273, in mkdir
    self._accessor.mkdir(self, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/hgovea155/airflow/logs/scheduler/2023-01-02'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/bin/airflow", line 5, in <module>
    from airflow.__main__ import main
  File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
    settings.initialize()
  File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 569, in initialize
    LOGGING_CLASS_PATH = configure_logging()
  File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/logging_config.py", line 74, in configure_logging
    raise e
  File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/logging_config.py", line 69, in configure_logging
    dictConfig(logging_config)
  File "/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/config.py", line 800, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/config.py", line 571, in configure
    '%r' % name) from e
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'processor'
```

I then gave export AIRFLOW_HOME=. after which I gave "airflow standalone" again and I received "airflow.exceptions.AirflowConfigException: Cannot use relative path: `sqlite:///./airflow.db` to connect to sqlite. Please use absolute path such as `sqlite:////tmp/airflow.db`."

```
standalone | Database ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 39, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 52, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/standalone_command.py", line 48, in entrypoint
    StandaloneCommand().run()
  File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/standalone_command.py", line 64, in run
    self.initialize_database()
  File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/standalone_command.py", line 183, in initialize_database
    appbuilder = cached_app().appbuilder
  File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/app.py", line 167, in cached_app
    app = create_app(config=config, testing=testing)
  File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/app.py", line 90, in create_app
    f'Cannot use relative path: `{conf.get("database", "SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN")}` to connect to sqlite. '
airflow.exceptions.AirflowConfigException: Cannot use relative path: `sqlite:///./airflow.db` to connect to sqlite. Please use absolute path such as `sqlite:////tmp/airflow.db`.
```

I then tried the fix provided by @kulasangar

I navigated to user -> airflow and changed the "logs" folder to read write and execute for all users. The "ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'processor'" error didn't occur but I received another error.

(venv) hgovea155@INSML-CPXX7WW AFDocProj % airflow standalone
standalone | Starting Airflow Standalone
standalone | Checking database is initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1901, in _execute_context
cursor, statement, parameters, context
File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 736, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/bin/airflow", line 8, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/**main**.py", line 39, in main
args.func(args)
File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 52, in command
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/standalone_command.py", line 48, in entrypoint
StandaloneCommand().run()
File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/standalone_command.py", line 64, in run
self.initialize_database()
File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/standalone_command.py", line 175, in initialize_database
db.initdb()
File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 75, in wrapper
return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 697, in initdb
_create_db_from_orm(session=session)
File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 682, in _create_db_from_orm
_create_flask_session_tbl()
File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 677, in _create_flask_session_tbl
db.create_all()
File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py", line 1094, in create_all
self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'create_all')
File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py", line 1086, in _execute_for_all_tables
op(bind=self.get_engine(app, bind), **extra)
File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 4931, in create_all
ddl.SchemaGenerator, self, checkfirst=checkfirst, tables=tables
File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3228, in _run_ddl_visitor
conn._run_ddl_visitor(visitorcallable, element, **kwargs)
File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2211, in _run_ddl_visitor
visitorcallable(self.dialect, self, **kwargs).traverse_single(element)
File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 524, in traverse_single
return meth(obj, **kw)
File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 855, in visit_metadata
_is_metadata_operation=True,
File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 524, in traverse_single
return meth(obj, **kw)
File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 900, in visit_table
include_foreign_key_constraints,  # noqa
File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1380, in execute
return meth(self, multiparams, params, _EMPTY_EXECUTION_OPTS)
File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 81, in _execute_on_connection
self, multiparams, params, execution_options
File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1478, in _execute_ddl
compiled,
File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1944, in *execute_context
e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2125, in *handle_dbapi_exception
sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from*=e
File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise*
raise exception
File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1901, in _execute_context
cursor, statement, parameters, context
File "/Users/hgovea155/PycharmProjects/AFDocProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 736, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) attempt to write a readonly database
[SQL:
CREATE TABLE session (
id INTEGER NOT NULL,
session_id VARCHAR(255),
data BLOB,
expiry DATETIME,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
UNIQUE (session_id)
)

]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)

Is there a way to fix this? I believe this problem is because of some mistake in the initial setup or configuration. Can a more proper fix be found rather than a temporary one.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the user doesn't have the privilege to write logs under your airflow distribution folder.

Could you try granting write permission to the folder, so that airflow instance can write logs

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/user/airflow_logs
```

Please change the logs directory accordingly.

Comment: That seems to have worked but now I'm getting another read only permission error.

I've added it to the main question.

Comment: hi @HENSELWILSONGOVEAS if the previous error was fixed you have to either accept the answer or upvote it and post a new question with the new exception as it'll be confusing for whoever refers it later